# DataGridView CellValueChanged event

Tags: c#

the event is triggered when the Form with the DataGridView is initialized, when the column headers texts are placed. So the function handling the event runs at start-up as many time as there are columns. How can I stop that and have it triggered only after the user made some changes in the datagrid?

Added:
It seems that changing from CellValueChanged to CellEndEdit does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the SelectionChanged property of the datagrid, triggering an event when the content changes?

```
<Grid>
<DataGrid> Name="TestDataGrid" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_EventName" />
</Grid>
```

Within the Code-Behind, the event will be captured:

```
private void DataGrid_EventName(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  //Conduct work here
}
```

Edit: I'm quite sure that you will still need to initialize the DataGrid.

For example, you can use this event to extract the row-specific information from within the DataGrid:

```
private void DataGrid_EventName(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  DataGrid _dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
  DataRowView selectedRow = _dataGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

  if (selectedRow != null)
  {
    RowItemList = new List<string>(); //List declared outside of this method...
    //add row information to the list
    RowItemList.Add(selectedRow.ToString());

    //or, get column-specific information
    string ColmnEntry = selectedRow[ColumnName].ToString();
  }
}
```